# Responsive table without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an issue with the project I'm working on (a simple presentation page for a driving school). I have created an accordion for driving signs and split them based on the sign type. Now, for each category of signs I have a table inside the accordion element.

The problem is that at first the site was designed for desktop only, but now I want to make it responsive. Everything else is done with @media queries, but I don't know what to do with the tables. They are designed to be 5 columns on desktop and one column on mobile (that's why I avoid using bootstrap - it would be difficult to make the 5 columns align and fit properly, or it has been so far).

This is what it looks like on desktop, and I want to keep this exact design. Please ignore the text - it is in my maternal language:

[image]

So, this is my CSS & HTML:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3097A4, #FFFBF4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3097A4, #FFFBF4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#3097A4, #FFFBF4);
  background: linear-gradient(#3097A4, #FFFBF4);
}

.main-box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1050px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
}


nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #305a7d;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 85%;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 210px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #254661;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li a:active {
  background-color: #254661;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color:#203c53;
}

.footer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1050px;
  text-align:right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #254661;
 }

.description {
  text-indent: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 85%;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
}

#left { 
   width:57%; 
   height: 100%;
   float:left; 
   margin-top: 50px; 
   padding-left: 2%; 
   padding-right: 2%;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 80%;
 display: block;
}

#right { 
 display: inline-block;
    width:35%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin-top: 50px;  
    padding-right: 4%;
}

/* Style inputs with type="text", select elements and textareas */
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 12px; /* Some padding */  
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #e8554e;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #9a3834;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 100%
    }

/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #36648b;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
.container-contact {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 480px;  
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #204a65;
}

#formular {
   text-align: center;
   color: #204a65;
   font-size: 160%;
   font-weight: bold;
}

#contactinfo {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;   
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;  
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 85%;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#contactinfo dl{
  color: #e8554e;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

#contactinfo dl dd{
  text-transform: initial;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: #204a65; 
  font-size: 95%;
  font-weight: initial;

}

#contactinfo a:link {
    color: #204a65; 
    background-color: transparent; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

#contactinfo a:visited {
    color: #204a65;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#contactinfo a:hover {
    color: #204a65;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#contactinfo a:active {
    color: #204a65;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#map{
 width: 340px;
 height: 340px;
 border: 1px solid silver
}

.acte-necesare {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  width: 80%;
}

.acte-necesare #titlu {
  color: #204a65;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 85%;
}

.acte-necesare ul{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 85%;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#art24 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#art24 li {
  font-size: 90%
}


.container-accordion {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.container-accordion #titlu {
  color: #e8554e;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.panel-content {
  padding: 0px;
}

.panel-group {
  padding-top: 15px
}

.table-indicatoare {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-indicatoare td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 85%;
}


@media screen and (min-width:350px) and (max-width:480px){
 .main-box{
  width: auto;
  display: block
 }
 nav li a{
  width: auto; 
 }
 nav li {
  float: none
 }
 .footer{
  width:auto
 }
  #right {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
 #left{
  width: auto;
  margin-top:auto;
 }
 .container-contact{
  width: auto;
 }
 #contactinfo{
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 10%
 }
 #map{
  width:85%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
 }
 .acte-necesare{
  padding-bottom: 20px
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="geo.region" content="RO-IL">
        <title>Legislatie</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top:30px; margin-left:8px; margin-right:8px">
      <div class="main-box">
        <header><img src="images/header.png" style="display:block">
        </header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" target="_self" style="font-size:13.6px">Despre noi</a></li>
            <li><a href="cursuri-auto-pret.html" target="_self" style="font-size:13.6px">Cursuri auto / Pret</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="#portrait" style="font-size:13.6px">Legislatie</a></li>
            <li><a href="acte-necesare.html" target="_self" style="font-size:13.6px">Acte necesare</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" target="_self" style="font-size:13.6px">Contact</a></li>
          </ul> 
        </nav>
        <div class="container-accordion">
          <div id="titlu">INDICATOARE RUTIERE</div>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">A. INDICATOARE DE AVERTIZARE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">
                  <table class="table-indicatoare">
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a1.jpg"><br/>Curba la stanga</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a2.jpg"><br/>Curba la dreapta</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a3.jpg"><br/>Curba dubla sau o succesiune de mai mult de doua curbe, prima la stanga</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a4.jpg"><br/>Curba dubla sau o succesiune de mai mult de doua curbe, prima la dreapta</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a5.jpg"><br/>Curba deosebit de periculoasa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a6.jpg" style="width: 60%"><br/>Panouri succesive pentru curbe deosebit de periculoase</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a7.jpg"><br/>Coborare periculoasa</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a8.jpg"><br/>Urcare cu inclinatie mare</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a9.jpg"><br/>Drum ingustat pe ambele parti</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a10.jpg"><br/>Drum ingustat pe partea dreapta</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a11.jpg"><br/>Drum ingustat pe partea stanga</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a12.jpg"><br/>Acostament periculos</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a13.jpg"><br/>Drum aglomerat</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a14.jpg"><br/>Tunel</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a15.jpg"><br/>Pod mobil</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a16.jpg"><br/>Iesire spre un chei sau mal abrupt</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a17.jpg"><br/>Drum cu denivelari</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a18.jpg"><br/>Denivelare pentru limitarea vitezei</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a19.jpg"><br/>Drum lunecos</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a20.jpg"><br/>Improscare cu pietris</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a21.jpg"><br/>Caderi de pietre</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a22.jpg"><br/>Presemnalizare trecere de pietoni</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a23.jpg"><br/>Copii</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a24.jpg"><br/>Biciclisti</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a25.jpg"><br/>Animale</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a26.jpg"><br/>Animale</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a27.jpg"><br/>Lucrari</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a28.jpg"><br/>Semafoare</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a29.jpg"><br/>Aeroport</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a30.jpg"><br/>Vant lateral</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a31.jpg"><br/>Circulatie in ambele sensuri</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a32.jpg"><br/>Alte pericole</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a33.jpg"><br/>Accident</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a34.jpg"><br/>Intersectie de drumuri</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a35.jpg"><br/>Intersectie cu un drum fara prioritate</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a36.jpg"><br/>Intersectie cu un drum fara prioritate</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a37.jpg"><br/>Intersectie cu un drum fara prioritate</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a38.jpg"><br/>Intersectii cu drumuri fara prioritate, decalate</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a39.jpg"><br/>Intersectii cu drumuri fara prioritate, decalate</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a40.jpg"><br/>Presemnalizare intersectie cu sens giratoriu</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a41.jpg"><br/>Trecere la nivel cu o cale ferata cu bariere sau semibariere</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a42.jpg"><br/>Trecere la nivel cu o cale ferata fara bariere</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a43.jpg"><br/>Trecere la nivel cu linii de tramvai</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a44.jpg"><br/>Masini si utilaje agricole<br/><br/></td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a45.jpg"><br/>Presemnalizarea unei amenajari rutiere care ofera si posibilitatea intoarcerii vehiculelor</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a46.jpg"><br/>Baliza directionala care indica ocolirea obstacolului prin stanga</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a47.jpg"><br/>Baliza directionala care indica ocolirea obstacolului prin dreapta</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a48.jpg"><br/>Baliza bidirectionala<br/><br/></td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a49.jpg"><br/>Panouri suplimentare pentru trecerea la nivel cu calea ferata</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a50.jpg"><br/>Panouri suplimentare la nodurile rutiere de pe autostrazi</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a51.jpg"><br/>Trecere la nivel cu o cale ferata simpla, fara bariere</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a52.jpg"><br/>Trecere la nivel cu o cale ferata dubla, fara bariere</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a53.jpg"><br/>Trecere la nivel cu o cale ferata simpla fara bariere</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/avertizare/a54.jpg"><br/>Trecere la nivel cu o cale ferata dubla fara bariere</td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">B1. INDICATOARE DE REGLEMENTARE - INDICATOARE DE PRIORITATE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">
                  <table class="table-indicatoare">
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/prioritate/b1.1.jpg"><br/>Cedeaza trecerea</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/prioritate/b1.2.jpg"><br/>Oprire</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/prioritate/b1.3.jpg"><br/>Drum cu prioritate</td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/prioritate/b1.4.jpg"><br/>&emsp; Sfarsitul drumului cu prioritate  </td>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/prioritate/b1.5.jpg"><br/>&emsp; Prioritate pentru circulatia din sens invers</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><img src="indicatoare/prioritate/b1.6.jpg"><br/>&emsp; Prioritate fata de circulatia din sens invers</td>
                      <td colspan="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">B2. INDICATOARE DE REGLEMENTARE - INDICATOARE DE INTERZICERE SAU RESTRICTIE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">Placeholder</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">B3. INDICATOARE DE REGLEMENTARE - INDICATOARE DE OBLIGARE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">Placeholder</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">C1. INDICATOARE DE ORIENTARE SI INFORMARE - INDICATOARE DE ORIENTARE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">Placeholder</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">C2. INDICATOARE DE ORIENTARE SI INFORMARE - INDICATOARE DE INFORMARE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">Placeholder</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7">C3. INDICATOARE DE ORIENTARE SI INFORMARE - INDICATOARE DE INFORMARE TURISTICA</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">Placeholder</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse8">D. PANOURI ADITIONALE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">Placeholder</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" style="color: #204a65; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size: 95%">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse9">E. INDICATOARE RUTIERE TEMPORARE</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-content">Placeholder</div>
              </div>
            </div>               
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">
        <br>Copyright &copy; Cristina Bendorfean 2017-2018
        <br> 
        <br> 
      </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please bear in mind that this is only my second project, and the first one I did was rather basic.

Comment: Probably you can use customized version of Bootstrap for table only from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes:

style.css:

```
.main-box {
   margin: auto;
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Also add the table-responsive attribute to each of your table. I have done for one of your div and table:

```
   <div class="panel-content table-responsive">
      <table class="table-indicatoare table">
```

Also, you will need to add nav-bar into your HTML page to make it look better when the page is rendered in mobile else it looks weird.